# JVM versus C++ compiler

Tags: java, c++, jvm

I have a query in which I cannot give a satisfactory answer. Java is notorious for its independence over machine architectures grace to JVM. I 've understood the following:

- Different JVM implementations are sitting on different machines as to produce the appropriate output (different for any different architecture) from the same input(.class files).

Let's now consider C++. Why not to do the same with Java? Namely, implement different C++ compiler versions for different architectures, feed them with the same source and make every compiler produce the appropriate output; just make C++ compiler to mimic JVM!

*This is my query since I cannot understand why Java is unique in that...*

Comment: You have it wrong. JVM implementations do not produce output from class files.

Answer (score 4):

The `C++` compiler already does that. The difference is that whereas class files are interpreted by the JVM, C++ applications aren't (usually) distributed as source files.

This of course also requires that you use standard libraries which are available for all the platforms. There's nothing very magical here. You have compiled languages such as C++, partially compiled like Java and interpreted such as Ruby.

Comment: Could you be more analytical? I still do not understand the uniqueness of Java. Thank you

Comment: @ILIAS How did you come up with the idea that Java is somehow unique?

Comment: @ILIAS - With Java you compile to a .class file, and the JVM does the rest of the translation at runtime. With C++, the compiler does all the work up front and produces an executable file directly. That's all there is too it. What makes Java "unique" is that it has a large company behind it, promoting it as unique. Just like Coca-Cola delivers "Open Happiness" and "A Refreshing Taste".

Comment: @Kayaman - Java is unique because Java promoters say it is! Drink the Cool-aid!

Comment: @BoPersson and Santa. http://www.coca-colacompany.com/stories/coke-lore-santa-claus/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is exactly what happens (as Kayaman said). You write one source, and compile it for different platforms, for example gcc/mingw or visual for Windows, gcc for Linux etc.

The difference between C/C++ and Java is that from C and C++ it is much easier to do direct system calls, to directly work with the filesystem, with sound devices etc. These system calls will differ for each system, which is what makes the code not portable. This means that portability for C++ code is the choice of the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you do that you have Java. If C++ doesn't have a direct connection with the low level resources than lots of advantages of this language disappear. It's kind of the same thing with C++ and assembling language. Creating a more high-level language will have a negative effect on the control of the machine's resources.

Read this about Java: [Java Architecture](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/introarch.html)